# In how many ways can five boxes be filled with either a red ball or a blue ball if no two adjacent boxes can be filled with blue balls?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Boxes numbered 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are kept in a row and they are to be filled with either a red or a blue ball such that no two adjacent boxes can be filled with blue balls. Then, how different arrangements are possible, given that all balls of a given colour are exactly identical in all respects?

*I tried as:
all red: _ _ _ _ _  $= 1$ combination;
4 red : _ _ _ _ $= 5$ combinations;
3 red : _ _ _ $= 6$ combinations;
2 red : _ _ $= 1$ combinations;
1 red : _ not possible;
Ans: $13$

But given answer is : $22$;
Solution provided: total possibilities $= 2^5 = 32$;
2 blue $=4$;
3 blue $=3$;
4 blue $=2$;
5 blue $=1$;
total $=10$;
Ans: $32-10 = 22$*

Comment: Your answer is okay. The given answer is wrong. They argue for instance that with $3$ blue balls only the possibilities BBBRR,RBBBR,RRBBB fall out. But e.g. also BBRRB will fall out.

Comment: thanks @drhab I was little bit confused.